Ruby-LSP won't stop indexing files
I installed the Ruby-LSP extension, set the "version manager" to RVM.
After restarting VS Code, it keeps showing "indexing files". I don't know why it never finishes.
Ruby LSP: indexing files: 0% completed

Software details:

Windows 10
WSL 2 | Ubuntu 22.04
RVM Version: rvm 1.29.12 (latest)
VS Code 1.92.1
Ruby-LSP 0.8.4

Steps to reproduce:
Install RVM
gpg2 --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

After trying to install ruby, I got an error. So I used the command
rvm get master

Then I installed ruby
rvm install ruby


I expected Ruby LSP extension to finish indexing the files.
